# Let $f:A→B$ be an injective function. Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $A$. Prove that if $f(S)\subseteq f(T)$, then $S\subseteq T$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve this proof but I'm not completely sure how to start.  Discrete has been pretty rough for me so far so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

***Hint:*** If $f(S) \subseteq f(T)$ then for every $s \in S$ there exists a $t \in T$ such that $f(s) = f(t)$. Recalling that $f$ is injective, what can you do with the previous equation?

Answer (score 0):

Option.

Assume $T \subset S$ (strict inclusion).

There is a $s \in S$ and $s \not \in T$.

$f(s)\not \in f(T)$ since $f$ is injective, a contradiction.

Hence $S \subseteq T$.